# ffmpeg / video stutters at 1 Hz when encoding image seq with 24 fps instead of 25 pfs

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am encoding an image sequence as mp4/h264 using ffmpeg. I notice that when I use `-r 24`, the playback (both in VLC, and the Gnome integrated desktop video player) "jumps forward" every second, as if the motion prediction or key frame calculation had gone wrong. In contrast, using `-r 25` produces a smooth playback. This is on a desktop computer (Debian) with a TFT that runs at 60 Hz, so that shouldn't have any influence in this bug.

Any ways to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg assumes a framerate of 25 for image sequences unless you override it.

So your command should start

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i img%d.jpg...
```

Don't put `-r` before `-i`.